# Can't make select filter JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase

I create a collections with the countries in cloud firebase, and a select box with a list of the countries in html/css. I want to create a filter which will show a list of selected countries. I've already created a functions which shows a specific countries for ex:

```
function showPoland(){
         db.collection("Poland").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
         querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
         // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
         console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
         renderCountries(doc);
     });
   });
}
```

and function which select countries from the select box:

```
 function selectCountry(){
        if(result =="Ukraine"){
          showUkraine();
       }
        else if(result=="Poland"){
    
          var x = document.getElementById("db-colection");
          x.style.display ="none";
          showPoland();
        }
     }
```

And here is the main problem:when I choose Ukraine I get it, but when I choose Poland then Polish cities are added to Ukrainian cities, but iI want to remove Ukrainian cities and show only Polish ones.

Comment: You need to provide more information.  You should provide the definition for showUkraine() and showPoland(), as that's where the bug is likely to lie.  You also need to provide your html code for anyone to be able to provide you with any help.

Comment: You should most probably re-initialize your array of countries, in `renderCountries();` probably. Without your entire code we cannot help you.